# jQuery Modal Dialog, ie6 secure non-secure error, https ssl

Tags: jquery, security, dialog, modal-dialog

(Please don't bother asking why we support ie6.)

We're creating custom Alert/Confirms using the jQuery Modal Dialog. I've created a div with xsl (In the examples, I took some of the xsl out and put in raw html to avoid confusion). The div is triggered using jQuery. I wrote a couple functions (that essentially open the dialog, pass a message, and a function) so we can implement the new alert/confirm using javascript (basically replacing alert(); with uiAlertError();).

Some of this information is not important. I can get more specific, but the main issue here is that in ie6 I get a "This page contains both secure and nonsecure items, Do you want to display the nonsecure items?" error. Everything works correctly in ie7, ie8, firefox, safari, and chrome.

From what I've read there are some common issues such as: http:// needing to be https:// (or http:// to //, change to relative opposed to absolute), src's that are empty, mixed content, etc. The underlying theme of all of this (from what I've gathered) is getting things to load secure, since we're on a secure page. But this is not my issue!

I've isolated the problem down to the something to do with jQuery (I tested the new code; got the error. Commented the new code out; error went away. I uncommented the xsl, but left the jQuery commented out; error was still gone. Commented the jQuery back in, the error came back).

Here is the javascript:

Here are the functions I wrote to replace the alert(); :

```
function uiAlertError(msg, ok_func){
    document.getElementById('alert_id_img').src="images/dialog_warning.png";
    uiAlert(msg, ok_func);
}
function uiAlertCheck(msg, ok_func){
    document.getElementById('alert_id_img').src="images/dialog_check.png";
    uiAlert(msg, ok_func);
}
function uiAlert(msg, ok_func){
    document.getElementById('alert_id_msg').innerHTML = msg;
    $("#alert_id").dialog("open");

    $("#alert_ok").click(function(){
        if(ok_func == undefined || ok_func == ''){
            $("#alert_id").dialog("close");
        }else{
            eval(ok_func);
            $("#alert_id").dialog("close");
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#alert_id").dialog( "destroy" );

    $("#alert_id").dialog({
        width: 325,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        minHeight: 90,
        autoOpen: false
    });
});
```

I'm sure it has something to do with either my jQuery implementation or jQuery itself.

This page is not hosted publicly.

Thanks for the help!
Tony

Comment: Nothing?

I also found that if I wrap $(function(){}); in a function such as runMe(); and then I call runMe(); as soon as I get into uiAlert(); it will suppress the error message from displaying when the page loads. The error message then loads when you execute the runMe(); function. This isolates it down to a small bit of code.

Comment: For anyone that runs across this in the future: The ie7 issue involved a browser add-on. For whatever reason there was an add-on running an 'http://', this is what made the error seem browser specific. For ie6 there appears to be some sort of correlation between page load and the $(function(){ call. If you wrap $(function(){}); in a function and then call that wrapper function just before you call the dialog, you will never get the error (in ie6). I'm working through another solution, but this is a quick fix (hackjob).

Comment: Another thought: I noticed bgiframe (which I think is jQuery version of the iframe divshim) initializes the jQuery like this: (function($){})(jQuery); oppose to the traditional $(function(){}); or $(document).ready(function(){});. This seems to work in ie6 without the secure non-secure warning, though it breaks the 'X' close button. To solve that, I just adjusted styling (we have a ie6 specific css file) I had to use float: right;, adjust some padding, remove an attribute, etc. Everything is working and ie6 is 98% working.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue working with jquery and xslt + ajax on IE6.

The problem is the destroy.  Put an alert(1) before the destroy and alert(2) after it, and you will see that the mixed security occurs between.

In my code it looks something like this:

```
    $("#box").dialog("close");
    alert(1);
    $("#box").dialog('destroy').remove();
    alert(2);
```

I'm still looking for a better way of disposing of the dialog, since I'm using ajax, the page keeps #box around and then you have 2 instances of #box if not properly disposed.

Comment: I still have the destroy in there and it's not having issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that same as my [one in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13401356/905) - there's a bug in the jQuery UI 1.8 CSS:

```
.ui-resizable-handle { position: absolute;font-size: 0.1px;z-index: 99999; display: block;
    /* http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7233
     - Resizable: resizable handles fail to work in IE if transparent and content overlaps
    */
    background-image:url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=);
}
```

Not only do IE6 and 7 not support data URIs, but any such base 64 strings are treated by IE as a nonsecure resource.

Replace this line with:

```
background-image:url(blank.gif);
```

Where `blank.gif` is a 1x1 transparent GIF and the error is fixed!

It looks like the jQuery UI guys [are aware of the issue](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7233#comment:15), and it's fixed in 1.9 and above.